# How do I protect against XSS/Injection when using jquery.append?

Tags: jquery, append, xss

I'm making a javascript code editor for users on my site. One of the features I built was a custom console.
Users can write console.log in their code and the logged string gets appended to a div on the page doing something like this:

```
  function toConsole(str) {
    var myconsole = document.getElementById("console-text");

    var message = document.createElement("span");
    message.append(str);

    myconsole.append(message);
}
```

`str` is set to whatever string the user inputs into `console.log`. Can appending this string run malicious code on my page? (The [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jQuery api page says 'yes' but I can't seem to get it to interpret anything I write as html)

If so how can I prevent this and how can I test to make sure it's safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text) to insert the content as a textNode, which will cause it not to be rendered by the page as markup, but as plain text.

```js
var stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript = '<div><b>This will be bold</b></div>';

$(document.body).text(stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript);
$(document.body).append(stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Taplar said, there are different ways.
You can also add the HTML to a temporarily-tag and extract the text afterwards.
See my third example to do this.

```js
$(function() {
  var stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript = '<div><b>This will be bold</b></div>';

  $('.test1').append(stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript);
  $('.test2').text(stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript);
  $('.test3').text($('<i/>').append(stringContainingHtmlAndJavascript).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jquery.append()** and **jquery.html()** are not secure against **XSS attack** Unless you sanitize the data when you want to display the that to the user.

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');}
```

but **jquery.text()** is safe because it does not render the html code and brings it in raw.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you [`.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) with a **bemol**, as stated in the documentation.

`.parseHTML()`, as the method name says, parses a string to interpret the HTML.
The third argument `keepScripts` is defaulted to false... Setting it to true would open the gates wide to scripts.

So it *"normally removes"* the script tags. If no HTML or text is found at all, it returns `undefined` (like demo case #3). So you problably will need to add an `if` condition to avoid appending the text *"undefined"*.

So... In the demo below, I used your posted "script to append" quite as-is... I just added the HTML parsing method.

**IMPORTANT**, case #1 to #4 are safe... **But #5 is a breach**. If there is an inline on[event] attribute in the parsed HTML, it will go through the *"script filter"* and may execute.

```js
$(".console_ok").on("click",function(){
  toConsole( $(this).prev(".console_input").val() );
});

function toConsole(str) {

  str = $.parseHTML(str)[0];

  var myconsole = document.getElementById("console-text");
  var message = document.createElement("span");
  message.append(str);

  myconsole.append(message);
}
```

```css
input{
  width: 60em;
}
#console-text{
  height:8em;
  width:20em;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

console.log test #1:<input class="console_input" value="Just text">
<button class="console_ok">OK</button><br>
<br>
console.log test #2:<input class="console_input" value="<h1>Some HTML</h1>">
<button class="console_ok">OK</button><br>
<br>
console.log test #3:<input class="console_input" value="<script>alert('A script!!!');</script>">
<button class="console_ok">OK</button><br>
<br>
console.log test #4:<input class="console_input" value="<div style='height:20px;background-color:red;'><script>alert('A script!!!');</script>And some <b>bold</b> text...</div>">
<button class="console_ok">OK</button><br>
<br>
console.log test #5:<input class="console_input" value="<img src='invalid-path' onerror='alert(`JS EXECUTES HERE!!!`);'>">
<button class="console_ok">OK</button><br>
<br>

My console:<br>
<div id="console-text"></div>
```

*(Please run in ful page mode)*
[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MxZZOj)

You will notice the `[0]` after `$.parseHTML(str)`... It's to get the DOM element from the jQuery object, as your function is plain JS. Your function could be written like this too *(does the exact same thing)*:

```
function toConsole(str) {

  str = $.parseHTML(str);

  var myconsole = $("#console-text");
  var message = $("<span>");
  message.append(str);

  myconsole.append(message);
}
```